# Как сделать Switch больше? Эта разметка используется для Xlarge - для планшетов . (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android

Как сделать Switch больше? Эта разметка используется  для  Xlarge - для планшетов .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

//

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch" />




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не будет работать на API ниже 21 -
вот ссылка как сделать для api 16+ (  в моём случае 16 возможно можно и  ниже)
[Не отображается ползунок Switch на API 16 (Android Studio Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990760/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-switch-%D0%BD%D0%B0-api-16-android-studio-java)

Если вы используете Api 21+ то ниже инструкция все будет работать!

Нужно создать в  drawable 2 файла.

1.rectangle_thumb.html

2.rectangle_tack.html

///

rectangle_thumb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <size android:height="70dp" android:width="70dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="8dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

rectangle_tack

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
       <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
    </shape>
</item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

Сам Switch выглядит так

```
<Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:text="Switch"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/rectangle_thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/rectangle_tack" />
```

Да и в values colors.xtml
нужно добавить

```
<color name="red">#ef2d09</color>
<color name="green">#1d701a</color>
```

Вот где указывается размер Switch

```
 <size android:height="70dp" android:width="70dp"/>
```

Фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]