# Не отображается ползунок Switch на API 16 (Android Studio Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Первое фото как должно быть, второе фото как работает на Api 16.
На Api к примеру 25 всё ОК.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

устанавливаю так

rectangle_tack.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

rectangle_thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
    <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="8dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:text="@string/activity2_Switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/rectangle_thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/rectangle_tack" />




</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Только так получилось реализовать .

работает как найти 16 так и выше +

45 задает размер устанавливается в верхней строчке два раза 
и в нижней строчке два раза ( короче изменяете все значения 45 на свои ) в файле sw_thumb.html

```
<size android:width="45dp" android:height="45dp"/>
```

Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        android:text="Power"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:thumb="@drawable/sw_thumb"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

sw_thumb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
            <size android:width="45dp" android:height="45dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="false" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFF"/>
            <size android:width="45dp" android:height="45dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#cdcdcd"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```